# Leave animation not working in Angular 6 component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a Notification component that's used to show notifications at the top of the screen. I want to have these notifications fade in and out. The `NotificationService` has an array of notifications. When a new notification is added, a timer is set via `setTimeout` that will remove the notification after 5 seconds.

The notifications appear and disappear correctly, but the fade animation is only working on the `:enter` transition, when the notification appears. When the notification is removed, it simply disappears without a fade animation.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**`notification.component.ts`:**

```
  animations: [
    trigger('fade', [
      transition(':enter', [style({ opacity: 0 }), animate('0.2s', style({ opacity: 1 }))]),
      transition(':leave', [style({ opacity: 1 }), animate('0.2s', style({ opacity: 0 }))])
    ])
  ]
```

**`notification.component.html`**:

```
<div @fade class="notification notification-{{ notification.theme }}">
  <div class="icon"><fa-icon [icon]="icons[notification.theme]"></fa-icon></div>
  <div class="message">{{ notification.message }}</div>
  <div class="close"><fa-icon (click)="closeButtonClicked()" [icon]="icons.close"></fa-icon></div>
</div>
```

**`app.component.html`**:

```
<div id="notification-container">
  <app-notification *ngFor="let notification of notifications" [notification]="notification"></app-notification>
</div>
```

**`app.component.ts`**:

```
  get notifications() {
    return this.notificationService.notifications;
  }
```

**`notification.service.ts`**:

```
export class NotificationService {
  notifications: Notification[] = [];

  showNotification(notificationToShow: Notification) {
    this.notifications = [notificationToShow, ...this.notifications];
    setTimeout(() => this.removeNotification(notificationToShow), 5000);
  }

  removeNotification(notificationToRemove: Notification) {
    this.notifications = this.notifications.filter(notification => notification !== notificationToRemove);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should put the `@fade` on the parent element (`<app-notification>`).

That element is responsible for creating / destroying each notification and as it doesn’t know about the animation on its child, it just removes it before any animation can happen.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get it working using this idea, but I had to make another change. I was wondering if you knew why I had to make this change. When I applied the `@fade` directly to the `<app-notification>`, it wasn't animating. But I wrapped the `<app-notification>` in a `<div>`, then it worked. Any idea why?

Comment: @JoeAttardi probably because by default component host doesn't have a `display` css property value. Adding `:host { display: block; }` in the component css would set its display and probably make the animation works ... to verify

Comment: this isn't an answer that helps at all. show them with code an example of the parent child relationship.